# Javascript get index on click

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using plain Javascript in a 3d art gallery. I have an image source array and am populating certain columns by pulling from this array. I need to get the index of the image on click so that I can use that to pull further information from said array...Titles, Descriptions.

I could do this with jQuery but I am trying to learn plain Javascript. I already have event listeners on all the images. Here is the current code:

```
var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
var subwrap = document.getElementById('subwrap');
var indexMatch;

for (var i=0; i <= imgList.length; i++){

    document.images[i].addEventListener("click", srcSend, false);

}

function srcSend(){

    var previewTitle = "Test Title";
    var previewText = "Test Description";
    var imgSrc = this.src;

    console.log('Image Source ='+''+imgSrc+'');

    if (imgSrc !== "file:///D:/Projects/mpaccione/img/navicon.png"){

    preview.className = " ";
    subwrap.className = "hide";
    preview.className = "show";
    preview.innerHTML = '<img src='+imgSrc+'><p id="title">'+previewTitle+'</p><p id="description">'+previewText+'</p>';   }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the Array.indexOf on the images collection.

```
function srcSend(){

    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.images, this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the index to the srcSend function.

```
for (var i=0; i <= imgList.length; i++){
    document.images[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        return (function(index) {
            srcSend(index);
        })(i);
    }, false);
}
```